# How to revert Apps Script project back to a GCP default project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

So I recently went through the steps to convert my Apps Script project to a GCP standard project using the docs at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project, and long story short my addon is hosed at the moment.  New users cannot install the addon and existing users need to re-authorize but when they do they receive the prompt that "Google hasn't verified this app".

How can I revert my addon back to using the GCP default project so my users aren't dead in the water?

Comment: From the link you posted, "You can't switch a script project to use a default GCP project."

Comment: @Diego Yeah, I had noticed that.  I was hoping maybe something like deleting the standard Project would switch it back to the default project.  The doc does state "the script's default GCP project is deleted", but I'm finding that not too be the case.  I can still see the default project, I'm just not able to revert back to it.

Comment: Well, the excellent engineers at Google were able to convert my old default GCP project into a Standard project for me.  When then allowed me to use it as the project for my Apps Script.  I'm back up and running, but it makes me wonder why the console didn't allow me to upgrade the old default GCP projects to Standard.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the excellent engineers at Google were able to convert my old default GCP project into a Standard project for me. When then allowed me to use it as the project for my Apps Script. I'm back up and running, but it makes me wonder why the console didn't allow me to upgrade the old default GCP projects to Standard